# It is impossible to create a new session Got this error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

"It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible"  Got this error for running script in selenium..how to solve this

Comment: please paste full stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

> was not found or it is not accessible

It means that the port which you tried to access is not available. [Ping](https://www.lifewire.com/ping-command-2618099) the server to double check it and run on [other port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959471/can-i-run-selenium-server-on-different-ports-at-the-same-time), if possible.